# Increasing functions which satisfy $f(2x)=2^{f(x)}$

Tags: functional-equations, monotone-functions

Does there exist an increasing function $f$ $>0$ for all $x> 0$ such that $$f(2x)=2^{f(x)} \text{ for } x>0?$$

I first considered sequences of the form $u_0=a$, for $a>0$ and $u_n=2^{u_{n+1}}$ to find $f(\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon$ very small but it doesn't work (not an infinite sequence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such function. Given your assumptions $f$ could be prolonged in $0$ by continuity (as $f$ is positive and increasing). But $a=2^a$ has no solution for $a>0$.

Comment: I don't get the fact that $f$ could be prolonged in $0$ by continuity... Could you explain that point ?

Comment: I understand it as follows: Look at the decreasing sequence $1>1/2>1/4> \ldots$. If $f$ is increasing, then the sequence $f(1) > f(1/2) > f(1/4) > \ldots$ is monotone and bounded, hence has some limit $a$. Then the two sides of the equality $f(1/2^{n-1}) = 2^{f(1/2^n)}$ converge to $a$ and $2^a$.